Why model training became extremely slow in PyTorch
I am encountering a strange behavior in the use of pytorch/cuda for training models: I noticed that training models that previously require little time to complete each training epoch, now require really much more time.
For example, a relatively simple model as this one, with a fixed dataset and trained on cuda used to take approximately 100 seconds per epoch, including forward, backward passes and some other small computation related to the training script (similar to this), whereas now the same exact script takes 30 minutes!
By assigning a tqdm meter to the batch loop, I can observe that only ~1.5 iterations per second are performed.
I noticed that this problem occurs especially in the presence of Conv2d modules (like the ones in the linked model); I understand that 2d convolution can be an expensive operation, but as I said, I didn't have this problem before.
Moreover, I also noticed that training on CPU is slowed down, perhaps the two things are correlated(?).
I originally encountered this problem with an installation of pytorch 2.2 and cuda 12.1, so thinking it was due to these versions, I re-ran a clean install of both, but the same problem also occurs with versions 2.4 and 12.4. I am working on a Windows machine and the nvidia driver I have is 551.78.
Can anyone tell me what the cause could be and/or what to check? Could this be due to compatibility issues with other libraries?
